# Delete record through ajax get

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In my application i loop through all record and generate a url for delete this record like this

```
<a href="category/delete/'.$row->catid.'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" onclick="return confirm(\'You are about to delete a record. This cannot be undone. Are you sure?\');" data-original-title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
```

which will generate

```
<a href="category/delete/1".....></a>
<a href="category/delete/2".....></a>
<a href="category/delete/3".....></a>
.......
```

here category is my controller and delete is my method and 1,2,3 are the record number.

My problem is i want to delete it through jquery GET method and display the successful message . But I can't understand how to achieve this. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Can you share any of your jQuery code?

Comment: ...or is that a secret?

Comment: no i dont have jquery code because i have to set id of my each <a> tag by which uniquely identify my element when i click. Thats why i cant understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this guy doesn't say anything. Lemme solve it:

```
$(function () {
  // Select all the links that start with category/delete/ and bind the click event.
  $('[href^="category/delete/"]').click(function (e) {
    // Prevent following the link.
    e.preventDefault();
    // Fire an AJAX request.
    $.get($(this).attr("href"), function (res) {
      // res is what your server responds.
      alert(res);
    });
  });
});
```